# Extract strings, that are the smallest part of other strings in the array or are unique

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have the following array:

```
str_ary = ["Thursday morning", "Twitter users", "Thursday morning , 140 characters",
"of Twitter users", "the virtual pockets of Twitter users","Beginning Thursday morning , 140 characters","in the virtual pockets of Twitter users"]
```

I want to filter it and get str_ary2 = ["Thursday morning", "Twitter users"].

Also if there is a unique string there (that is not part of any of other string, I want to keep it as well..).

What would be the best way to do it?

Now I have this, but it does not work...

```
def select_correct_sizes(arrays)
  result = []
  arrays.each do |a|
    arrays.each do |b|
      res = nil
      if b != a
        if a.split(' ').length >= b.split(' ').length
          res = self.substract_and_check(a, b)
        elsif a.split(' ').length < b.split(' ').length
          res =  self.substract_and_check(b, a)
        end
        if !res.nil?
          result << res
        end
      end
    end
  end
  result = result.uniq
  return result
end

def substract_and_check(a, b)
  res = a.gsub(/#{b}/, '')
  res = res.split(' ')
  if res.length + b.split(' ').length == a.split(' ').length
    puts "#{b} IS PART OF THE #{a}"
    return b
  elsif text_uniq?(a,b)
    puts "#{b} IS UNIQUE"
    return b
  else
    return nil
  end
end


def text_uniq?(a,b)
  res = a.gsub(/#{b}/, '')
  res = res.split(' ')
  if res.length == a.split(' ').length
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end


str_ary2 = select_correct_sizes(str_ary)
```

EDIT: Sorry if the question is not quite clear.. 
I need to extract strings, that are

A) 1)present in other strings from array 
    2)smallest in size
 B) 1) Unique (e.g. not present in any other strings from the array).

All the strings are filtered phrases, so there won't be anything like random individual junk words like "the", "one" etc..

In the above example "Twitter users" and "Thursday morning" are both present in other strings from the array.

So if the array included something like  "green ball", I need to extract it as well, because it is unique relative to other strings in the array.

Hope it is more clear now, please let me know otherwise.

EDIT2: I don't expect anyone to use the above code for answer, I will accept a different code or a well-detailed pseudo-code as well..

Comment: Do you need to extract these two exact strings? Your criteria is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, i will update the question, - I need to extract smallest strings that are part of other strings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want *all the elements which don't include any other element*.

```
str_ary = ["Thursday morning", "Twitter users", "Thursday morning , 140 characters",
  "of Twitter users", "the virtual pockets of Twitter users",
  "Beginning Thursday morning , 140 characters","in the virtual pockets of Twitter users",
  'green ball']

str_ary.reject{|e| (str_ary - [e]).any?{|e1| e.include?(e1)}}
# => ["Thursday morning", "Twitter users", "green ball"]
```